# SharePoint 2010: Application Pages Throwing Error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, site, application-pages

I am facing very strange issue.
I have created a site template from a site which has simply Wiki Pages, Lists and Libraries. Lists are using some Content Types which already exist in parent site.

I can create a site using that template, it creates successfully, work well but application pages like settings(_layouts/settings.aspx), permission, etc. pages are throwing "Unexpected error occurred".

FYI: I am not using Publishing pages but few site at top level are using Publishing feature.

Please help!

Thank you,
Amit

Comment: Can you include ULS details?

Comment: Sorry! I don't have access to it, I also want to take a look in that.

Answer (score 0):

This [forum post was helpful](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9cc3f90b-1ab7-4174-8e9c-e4e36080a80e/create-site-from-template-get-error-when-accessing-site-settings?forum=sharepointgeneral) and I resolved my issue.

The issue was due to alternate css I used. Here are the steps that I used to fix:

**Step 1:** Reset to default CSS so that template won't include alternate css file:

> Site Actions > Site Settings > Master Page

**Alternate CSS URL**:
**Select option**: Use Microsoft SharePoint Foundation default styles
**Check** :  Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL
Hit OK

**Step 2**: Create site template
(*This template will work fine now*)

**Step 3**: Set back to your alternate CSS from Master Page settings